# How to set the jsessionid cookie with jsoup?

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup, jsessionid

I have a problem with the following test method for authentication to the site of the university .
I'm using Jsoup and I can not get the cookies (jsessionid) to login .
The method is this :

```
public static void Authentication() {

    String strURL = "https://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/auth/Logon.do";
    String strUserId = "prova";
    String strPasword = "prova";

    String authString = strUserId + ":" + strPasword;

    String encodedString = new String( Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()) );

    try{

        Response response = Jsoup.connect(strURL)
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString)
                .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET)
                .timeout(30000)
                .execute();

        System.out.println(response.parse());

        System.out.println("Autenticato");

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the cookie creating another request to the home of the website.

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow38768839;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 38768839 answer.
 *
 */
public class App {

    private static final String COOKIE_NAME = "JSESSIONID";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Step 1 - Get the cookie
        String homeURL = "https://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/Home.do";
        Response response = Jsoup.connect(homeURL).execute();
        String jsessionid = response.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
        System.out.println(COOKIE_NAME + " cookie: " + jsessionid);

        // Step 2 - Try to login
        String strURL = "https://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/auth/Logon.do";
        String strUserId = "prova";
        String strPasword = "prova";

        String authString = strUserId + ":" + strPasword;

        String encodedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(authString
                .getBytes()));

        try {

            response = Jsoup.connect(strURL)
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString)
                    .cookie(COOKIE_NAME, jsessionid)
                    .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET).timeout(30000)
                    .execute();

            System.out.println(response.parse());

            System.out.println("Autenticato");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The help for the cookie was very good. Now the problem is that it doesn’t log in and gives me error 401, although the access credentials are correct. The error is in the “execute” function.

Comment: @VincEnzo The thing is that I can't test it if I haven't the credentials.

Comment: You can leave me your email? You send the login credentials